# Moving between HTTP and HTTPS in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I've found the [RequiresHttps] attribute but once your in https your kind of stuck there, so to try and be able to have actions on a single url (and scheme) I've found I've ended up having to create my own ExtendedController to revert back to http for actions that don't use [RequireHttps].

Just wondering if what I'm doing is okay or if there is a better way?

```
public class ExtendedController : Controller
{
    protected virtual void HandleHttpRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot post between https and http.");
        }
        string url = "http://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
    }

    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        object[] attributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        if (!attributes.Any(a => a is RequireHttpsAttribute))
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                this.HandleHttpRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I have just realised is that I should also check on filterContext.IsChildAction - I wonder if there is potential to run into the same issues using RequiresHttp on child actions. Seems like a more complete solution is needed perhaps on routing side instead of on controllers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you have is syntatically correct, however a suggestion is to create a new Action filter that inherits from the default RequireHttpsAttribute and takes a parameter to switch between http and https.

```
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    public bool RequireSecure = false;

    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)

    {
        if (RequireSecure)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            // non secure requested
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                HandleNonHttpRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void HandleNonHttpRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // redirect to HTTP version of page
            string url = "http://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
        }
    } 
}
```

Then, on your action method or controller you would use:

```
[RequireHttps (RequireSecure = true)]
```

...

or

```
[RequireHttps (RequireSecure = false)]
```

Comment: One thing to note is this defaults to non-secure "public bool RequireSecure = false;" whereas the System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute requires HTTPS. If you want to parallel the System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute just set the default to "true".

Answer (score 1):

To make it little more manageable. This solution assumes that majority of your web application use **HTTP** scheme.

1. Create new action filter RequiresHttp (use HTTP if NeedSsl attribute is not apply explicitly on action or controller),

   ```
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
       HttpResponseBase res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

       bool needSsl = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(NeedSslAttribute), true)
                       || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(NeedSslAttribute), true);


       if (needSsl && !req.IsSecureConnection) //https: secure
       {
           var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url)
           {
               Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
               Port = 444
           };
           res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
       }
       else if (!needSsl && req.IsSecureConnection) //http: non secure
       {
           var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url)
           {
               Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp,
               Port = 8081
           };
           res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
       }
       base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   }
   ```
2. And new blank attribute NeedSSL (for indication purpose)

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
   public sealed class NeedSslAttribute : Attribute { }
   ```
3. Apply RequiresHttp as global action filter in Global.aspx.cs

   ```
   public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
   {
       filters.Add(new RequiresHttp());
   }
   ```
4. Now apply apply NeedSslAttribute on controllers and actions where do you want to use HTTPS scheme

   ```
   [NeedSsl]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult LogOn()
   ```

This code is not perfect as action filter `RequiresHttp` does multiple jobs i.e. check `NeedSsl` attribute and apply `HTTP` or `HTTPS` scheme. Would have been better if we could use two action filters `RequiresHTTP` and `RequiresHTTPS`.

Now if `RequiresHTTP` was set as global filter and `RequiresHTTPS` filter was applied on specific actions and specific `RequiresHTTPS` filter would have given preference.